# Hierarchial Query to return child rows SQL : Connect By

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I  have three table that look(just an example) as follows

```
Artifact 
Id Name     
1  abc
2  xyz
3  pqr
4  mno

Classification 
Id Artifact_Id Node_id 
c1 1             n3
c2 1             n4
c3 3             n5
c4 4             n3
c5 4             n2

taxonomy_Node
Id  Parent_id
n1  null
n2  n1
n3  n1
n4  n2
n5  n3
```

So every artifact can have many classification(a hierarchy made of taxonomyNode i.e many nodes). Based on a taxonomyNode I want a list of artifacts that contain that node or its child.
I am trying to return a list of artifact when they have classification belonging to a taxonomy_node. Also If the parent of any node is given as ID it should return the artifact containing the child node. I am not really clear here. Please let me know if you have any doubts.

```
select A.* from artifact A 
   inner join classification C 
    on A.id = C.ARTIFACT_ID
   inner join TAXONOMY_NODE T 
    on C.node_id=T.id
    where T.id = 5068
  START WITH T.ID = 5068
  CONNECT BY PRIOR T.ID = T.parent_id
```

For example look at classification table artifact 4 has two class c4 and c5 with node n2 and n3. So when I give node-id as n3 it should  give me artifact 4 and also artifact 1 (as it contains n3) and also artifact 3 (as n3 is parent of n5). Similarly when i give node-id as n2 it should return 4 and 1

Comment: Um... are you attempting to use `CONNECT BY` in MySQL?

Comment: no sorry. using SQL developer

Comment: `CONNECT BY PRIOR` is not available for MySQL, as you've tagged the question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#CONNECT_BY

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*
with Artifact as (
select 1 id,  'abc' name from dual
union all select 2,  'xyz' from dual
union all select 3,  'pqr' from dual
union all select 4,  'mno' from dual
),
Classification as (
select 'c1' id, 1 Artifact_Id, 'n3' Node_id from dual
union all select 'c2', 1, 'n4' from dual
union all select 'c3', 3, 'n5' from dual
union all select 'c4', 4, 'n3' from dual
union all select 'c5', 4, 'n2' from dual
),
taxonomy_Node as (
select 'n1' id, null Parent_id from dual
union all select 'n2',  'n1' from dual
union all select 'n3',  'n1' from dual
union all select 'n4',  'n2' from dual
union all select 'n5',  'n3' from dual
)
*/
select a.* 
from classification c 
     join (select id from taxonomy_node start with id = 'n3' connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id) h
     on (c.node_id = h.id)
     join artifact a on (a.id = c.artifact_id);
```

The problem with your query is that Oracle makes all joins first and then apply CONNECT BY.

Comment: Those table were just examples. I need something generic

Comment: @krs8785 I know :) But I need some data for tests